# Cannot stringify or parse JSON data, AJAX request

Tags: javascript, json

Hi so I'm trying to grab two sets of JSON data and combine them into one set of data so I can use the data as needed, however, I'm running into a slight issue.

Here is my code

```
<script>
  (function() {
    const jobPositions = document.getElementById('jobPositions');

    const jobs = $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "https://www.welcomekit.co/api/v1/external/jobs?access_token=REDAC&organization_reference=REDAC&websites=true&status=published",
      success: function(result) {}
    });


    const jobDepartments = $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "https://www.welcomekit.co/api/v1/external/departments?access_token=REDAC&organization_reference=REDAC",
      success: function(result) {}
    });

    $.when(jobs, jobDepartments).done(function(a1, a2) {
      var data = a1[1] + a2[1];

      $.each(JSON.stringify(data), function(i) {
        var start = i++;

        console.log(data);

        if (start) {
          $(jobPositions).append('\
          <a target="_blank" href="'+ a1.websites.url +'" class="jobPosition-item d-md-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap">\
            <div>\
              <span class="jobPositions-name">' + a1.name + '</span>\
            </div>\
            <div class="right right-info d-flex align-items-center">\
              <span class="jobPositions-profession">' + a2.department_id + '</span>\
              <div class="d-flex">\
                <img src="/hubfs/www/about/white-icon-arrow.png" height="11" width="11" alt="arrow">\
              </div>\
            </div>\
          </a>\
          ');
        };
      });
    });
  })();
</script>
```

When I run this I'm getting `jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in "successsuccess"`, so I change `$.each(JSON.stringify(data), function(i) {` to `$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i) {`.

I get the following

```
VM1330:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
```

Any help here or improvements to the code would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: try just `$.each(data` --- you specified `dataType : "json"` in the AJAX request. This means jQuery already parses the JSON and converted the data to an object for you before it gives you the response. No need to parse it again. (And why you tried stringifying it is beyond me...looping through a string is not going to be useful)

Comment: update your question showing what's on a1, a2 and data

Comment: @ADyson I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in successsuccess`

Comment: are you sure both requests end with success? add an error handler

Comment: Ah sorry I just noticed, it's because you're combining the results in a weird way. `var data = a1[1] + a2[1];` just combines two of the values from the results together...and those two values appears to be two strings which both say "success". So no wonder you can't loop over them. Did you intend to combine both result sets in some way? The later code just references a1 and a2 directly anyway. It might help if you showed us the content of a1 and a2...then we can see how to process them sensibly.

Comment: How would you recommend in combining them @ADyson, this is my first time passing through two AJAX requests so want to make sure that I'm doing it right haha I want to pass all the data if I can.

Comment: That depends on a) what the structure of them is, and b) what you want the end result to look like. Without knowing the given input and the required output, it is very hard to try and define the process... :-). Please give us an examples of the content of a1 and a2, and what you want the final HTML output to look like. Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully this helps @ADyson https://pastebin.com/mtxmdSfK everything for the end result is coded I just need to be able to pass the data.

Comment: Thanks but to make the question complete for future readers (and in case the paste gets deleted or changed) please add it here in the question instead. Use the "edit" button add the info. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I'll edit it but does that help you help with passing in the data @ADyson

Comment: P s. You still need to provide sample output so I can understand the desired result. I can't assume all that code is correct necessarily, and it's much easier to work from an actual example of the finished HTML anyway

Comment: Yes that info is helpful, thanks. Along with the sample output it will give a good picture I think

Comment: @ADyson Hopefully this helps https://pastebin.com/J0K39sj2

Comment: In what meaningful way are you trying to merge the two arrays `jobs` and `jobDepartments` - it seems to me that you'd at least need to figure out which `job` has to do with which `jobDepartment`

Comment: @James Basically, the job name and URL is in the jobs section of the API and the department is in the job departments of the API, so to output what I need to output I'm trying to combine the two arrays if possible so I can output the data that I need to output.

Comment: So the first thing in the job list is always related to the first thing in the jobDepartments list, and it's a 1:1 match all teh way down?

Comment: @James There separate arrays and outputs https://pastebin.com/mtxmdSfK A1 being the response from the jobs API and A2 being the response from the job departments API. So for jobs, I need the name and websites URL and from the job departments response, I need the name.

Comment: How do you know which job dept is with which job, or is there always a single job and a bunch of job departments which are all to do with that one single job?

Comment: I believe a job belongs to a department @James but as jobs response doesn't include the department only it's ID then it seems I need to do two responses and output. That's what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: But the dept id is null.  You would need to 1.  have a dept id in the job record then 2.  search the jobDepartments array for the element with the correct department Id.

Comment: For jobs, I'm skipping the first response as that's not relevant all other records have a `"department_id": 10894,` <- ex. this is the matching department https://pastebin.com/JXWb5ZJi.

So jobs have a department_id but I need to go into the matching department's array and get the name. @James

Answer (score 1):

The actual data seems to be contained in the first element of the structures being passed into the done function.  So by slightly changing the code to target the first elements of each a1 and a2 it should work:

```
$.when(jobs, jobDepartments).done(function(a1, a2) {

  $.each(a1[0], function (i, item) {
    // get the department
    var dept = a2[0].find(jobDept => jobDept.id == item.department_id);
    // get its name
    var deptName = dept && dept.name || "Unknown Dept";

    console.log(deptName);

  });

});
```

Comment: It seems that I can only pass stuff when passing in the specific item i.e. `const deptName = dept[1].name;` as in it isn't actually looping through all items.

Comment: I've tried stringifying the data like so but still getting `undefined` https://pastebin.com/m7Z0U8PG